# Why does Visual Studio 2010 recompile my C# project on debug restart?

Tags: c#, performance, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to ask, but as it's programming related, here it is:

I have a solution with several projects (all .NET/C# based. some libraries, some WPF, some XNA, some portable class library, all together) and I have problems with performance:

1. While running my project, when I hit restart (Ctrl+Shift+F5) while debugging, the instance stops, VS **recompiles** all the projects in the solution again, and then it runs again.
2. When I stop my running instance. Without touching any code (not even spacebar in the code editor), I hit F5 and similarly, it again recompiles the whole solution.
3. When I'm working in only one of the projects and hit Debug without touching any code in the other projects in the solution, VS, again, recompiles all the projects in the solution.

This creates a real bottleneck as my project normally starts in <1 sec. but it compiles for a few seconds even on SSD. A few seconds don't seem much but I make some very small changes to only one code file and try something several times by running the application again and again, it becomes a real trouble.

Comment: Maybe a problem with your pc clock, or the time of your repository. If for some reason your file times differ from your system clock, vs might get confused and thinks "Its outdated, better recompile". But thats just an idea.

Comment: after your comment, I've realized the problem. it was the BuildVersionIncrement plugin which increments the assembly version on each build. I disabled it and the problem is gone. but now, I need a way to solve it without disabling the plugin, if possible.

Comment: Plugins like that were designed to be used on a build server.  It just gets in the way on your dev machine so just get rid of it.  Or improve it so it only increments for Release builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out the reason and the problem is solved. I was using BuildVersionIncrement plugin and it was incrementing the build number every time I compile, and Visual Studio was thinking that, because of the change in files, the project was outdated, thus, bebuilding the whole solution. I changed the BuildVersionIncrement settings to increment only on full rebuild, and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you have your studio setup to always build, it will do so. Make sure you have the correct settings in studio. See below.

[image]

Comment: That setting only takes effect "when projects are out of date" - the real cause of the problem is that VS thinks the code requires a rebuild. If you set it to "never build" then you run the risk of running code that doesn't include your latest changes.

Comment: Right, it should be set to prompt to build. However, he already figured out that it was a plugin which was increasing the version of the project and that was causing the issue.

Comment: i've changed some settings in the buildversionincrement (WHEN it increments) and selected fresh rebuilds only. now it doesn't increment on every build.

Comment: This option only applies to Visual C++ projects (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyhcc7zc(v=vs.100).aspx).  It had no effect on my C# project.